# Clarification on type inclusions in record in Ballerina

Tags: ballerina, ballerina-swan-lake

I have defined records like this:

```
type Record1 record {|
    int a;
    string b;
    string...;
|};


type Record2 record {|
    boolean c;
    string[] d;
    int...;
|};

type Record record {
    *Record2;
    *Record1;
};
```

How does the type inclusions work here?

When I make the record close like this:

```
type Record record {|
    *Record2;
    *Record1;
|};
```

Then it shows an error as expected: cannot use type inclusion with more than one open record with different rest descriptor types

But when I do something like this then the error is gone:

```
type Record record {|
    *Record2;
    *Record1;
    float...;
|};
```

In this case there should be an error right? Or am I missing something

I tried to refer to the spec here: https://ballerina.io/spec/lang/master/#section_5.4.2.2.
But I could not understand the overriding part.
Appreciate any input on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inclusion includes the rest descriptor also. So it results in a conflict when you do

```
type Record record {|
    *Record2;
    *Record1;
|};
```

since the compiler cannot identify the rest descriptor to use. Note that this is not a closed record.

For example, if there was no conflict, you could add rest fields to Record.

```
type Record1 record {|
    int a;
    string b;
    int...; // changed to int
|};

type Record2 record {|
    boolean c;
    string[] d;
    int...;
|};

type Record record {|
    *Record2;
    *Record1;
|};

Record r = {
    a: 0,
    b: "",
    c: false,
    d: [],
    "e": 1 // allowed since the rest descriptor is int
};
```

If you want to make it closed, you can use never...;.

```
type Record record {|
    *Record2;
    *Record1;
    never...;
|};
```

Inclusion of these types also works when you use an inclusive record typedesc

```
type Record1 record {|
    int a;
    string b;
    string...;
|};

type Record2 record {|
    boolean c;
    string[] d;
    int...;
|};

type Record record {
    *Record2;
    *Record1;
};
```

because this is equivalent to

```
type Record record {|
    *Record2;
    *Record1;
    anydata...;
|};
```